# Build error Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при компиляции возникает ошибка "error: class BuildConfig is public, should be declared in a file named BuildConfig.java". Возможно кто-то сталкивался.

Comment: `Класс с именем BuildConfig публичный, должен быть объявлен в файле с именем BuildConfig.java`

Comment: Ну так он там и объявлен.

Comment: Так ява или котлин?

Comment: Kotlin, файл BuildConfig создаеться автоматически

Comment: Проверьте все импорты с BuildConfig, возможно где-то не тот используется.